# Implemented Azure AD Client Creds flow but failing while validating the access token on the server end due to missing 'scp' property

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, access-token

1. Registered the App in Azure AD and followed client credentials grant.
2. Implemented the below to fetch the access token
   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-nodejs-console
3. Implemented the below to validate the access token
   https://github.com/playerony/validate-azure-ad-token

While running the validate azure ad token, experiencing this error "Error: The token's payload does not contain "scp" property". Need help in resolving the same.

Establishing API1(client end) accessing another API2(server end) on different platform. Registered API2 on Azure AD and defined client secrets. As provided the implementation links for fetching the access token and validating the access token, i am seeing "Error: The token's payload does not contain "scp" property".

Answer (score 0):

The error , `the token's payload does not contain "scp" property"` occurs when application permissions are not granted admin consent by Administrator.

I did not receive scopes  which are nothing but roles when application permissions are given.

[image]

It Is because they are not granted admin consent.

[image]

When they are given a proper consent through portal by admin or during users login .

Then they can be seen. ***So while calling other API please make sure you have each of the scopes given admin consent granted .***

[image]

Then you can see them reflected in token which is used to call API:
Please make sure to give scopes with /.default  when using client_credential flow.

Example:  `api://xxxxxxx/.default`

> Make sure to check mark Id_token in authentication blade .

Comment: Thank you @kavya Saraboju for your response. I do see API permission was added for the API in Azure AD while registration and see User.Read has been provisioned.

Comment: Clicked send before i adding something, even with the "user.Read" api permissions in the Azure AD for this API, i see this issue "the token's payload does not contain "scp" property"". So i am missing anything else in here?

Comment: In your code , please check if the scopes are included ..For example for graph : `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` .Also attach an image of your api permissions given to access api2 .